# How to Manually Calculate Intercept (Beta 0) and Coefficient (Beta 1) in Logistic Regression?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, regression, data-mining, logistic-regression

I'm currently studying about Logistic Regression. But i'm getting stuck at calculating Intercept (Beta 0) and Coefficient (Beta 1). I've been looking for it through the internet, but only get tutorials using Microsoft Excel or built-in function in R. I heard it can be solved by Maximum Likelihood, but i don't understand how to use it, because i don't have a statistical background. Is anyone can give me a brief explanation and simulation about calculating Intercept (Beta 0) and Coefficient (Beta 1)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no closed form solutions for logistic regression, but there are many iterative methods to learn its parameters. One of the simplest ones is steepest descent method, which simply iteratively moves in the opposite direction to the gradient. For 1D logistic regression it would be:

```
beta1_t+1 = beta1_t - alpha * SUM_(x, y) x * (s(beta1_t*x + beta0_t) - y)
beta0_t+1 = beta0_t - alpha * SUM_(x, y) (s(beta1_t*x + beta0_t) - y)
```

where:

```
s(x) = 1 / (1 + exp(-x))
```

and

- `alpha` is learning rate, something small enough, like 0.01
- your model's prediction is `s(beta1 * x + beta0)`
- your data is of form `{(x1, y1), ..., (xK, yK)})` and each `yi` is either 0 or 1

This is literally saying

```
beta_t+1 = beta_t - alpha * GRAD_theta J(beta_t)
```

where `J` is logistic loss